# Xlwings - Delete similarly named sheets using loop

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am using xlwings to place stock data I pull from the internet into worksheets. The workbook opens with a `Sheet1`, and upon running my program creates various sheets named according to the stock index. This leaves `Sheet1` and causes problems with other methods I want to call. I want to test for any sheets that contain `Sheet` (plus an integer) and subsequently delete it similar to how you would test for the presence of a list element using the `in` operator. How would I go about doing this in xlwings? Current xlwings methods only allow sheets in which you manually name to be deleted.

My attempts have been rather lackluster. I've been trying loops to recognize the sheet names but to no avail. Here is my attempt to do so.

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('practice.xlsx')
for sheet in wb.sheets:
    if 'Sheet' in sheet: 
        xw.Sheet[sheet].delete()
```

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('practice.xlsx')
for sheet in wb.sheets:
    if 'Sheet' in sheet.name: 
        sheet.delete()
```

Comment: this works in windows 10 but not in windows 7

Answer (score 0):

is the syntax more like sheet.api.Delete()? My xlwings is broken right now to check the exact syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can check, if the given sheet exist and you can delete the existing sheet and add a new one.

```
import xlwings as xw
def df_to_excel_util(excel,sheet_to_dataFrame_map):

    with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
        wb = app.books.open(excel)            
        current_sheets = [sheet.name for sheet in wb.sheets]
        
        for sheet_name in sheet_to_dataFrame_map.keys():
            if sheet_name in  current_sheets:
                wb.sheets[sheet_name].delete()
            
            new_sheet = wb.sheets.add(after=wb.sheets.count)
            new_sheet.range('A1').value = sheet_to_dataFrame_map.get(sheet_name)
            new_sheet.name = sheet_name
        wb.save()
```

**if you have sheet object, you can delete as given below**

```
sheet.delete()
```

**if you want to delete a sheet with a given name.**

```
wb.sheets['sheet_name'].delete
```